# flutter Image_picker and Image_gallery_saver permissions to access phone gallery

Tags: image, flutter, permissions, picker

I am new to flutter but I have a simple question.

I got my image picker plug in running fine on the emulator.  When I go to run my app on a regular phone the image picker doesn't work. I was wondering if I have to ask user permission to save a photo to their gallery ?  I was checking out some videos of permissions but I am wondering if I am on the right track.

```
adding to pubspec.yaml:
permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.6
image_gallery_saver: ^1.2.2
image_picker: 0.6.3+4


adding to AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks, 
Ash

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

</application>
```

add this in manifest under <application tag if no camera is opening

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, `image_picker` works.

If you do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">`, then you either need to:

Request permission manually before calling `ImagePicker.pickImage` the first time
Or Use another plugin which requires camera permissions first, and then use the `ImagePicker`.